# VS Code debug in Chrome - This site can’t be reached error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know this question has been asked before, but after reading a lot of the threads, I still haven't found my answer...

I am trying to debug a very simple html app with Chrome, but when I get to my localhost I get an error that says "This site can’t be reached". My launch.json code looks like this:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9222,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }

]
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated as I have been struggling for quite a while with this now.

Comment: Do you have anything running a server?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to run it in Chrome using the Chrome extension in VS Code.

Comment: You need to start your own server

Comment: Thanks @RobLourens. How do you do that? Sorry, I am new to vs code and still trying to figure it all out. Is there a tutorial somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Rob-Lourens has mentioned you need to start your own local server to host your HTML/Javascript/CSS and images.

You can use a VS code plugin [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) to create a local development server for you. Please make sure your URL(`"url": "http://localhost:3000"`) in your configuration file matches the URL of Live Server.

If you are on Windows and want to use IIS or IIS Express you can read up on [IIS](https://www.iis.net/) and [IISExpress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tjaart. I've managed to run my app by right-clicking on my .html file and clicking "open withLive Server", after installation. I tried using the port number in Live Server to run the app using launch.json, but it still didn't work which was strange. I will just use the "right-click" method for now.

Comment: Great, if my answer helped you please mark as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value in launch.Json and remove unwanted and paste the html file location in the file attribute.

{
"configurations": [

```
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Open index.html",
        "file": "C:\\Users\\xyz\\projects\\PracticeProjects\\jsbasics\\index.html"
    }
]
```

}