# need to open debug and shows page to localhost:8080

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-code, launch

I need to open browser in debug and he link where the google chrome need to open is

```
localhost:8080
```

In my `luch.json`  I have:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "url":"http://localhost:8080",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Open index.html",
            "file": "c:\\Users\\franc\\Desktop\\Angular js\\Progetti\\Modulo 4 routing\\codice mio\\index.html",
        
        }
    ]
    
}
```

the problem is the google chrome debug is to this link:

```
file:///C:/Users/franc/Desktop/Angular%20js/Progetti/Modulo%203%20Controlli/Codice%20mio/index.html/orders
```

and nothing is loaded. Anyone can help me to open debug console with visual studio code in loalhost:8080 and it loads data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code debug in Chrome - This site can’t be reached error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220273/vs-code-debug-in-chrome-this-site-can-t-be-reached-error)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your configurations,

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Debug in Chrome",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9229,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "debug:start"
        ],
        "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
            "${webRoot}/**",
            "!**/node_modules/**"
        ]
    }
]
```

Run `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9229` from your terminal/cmd.

workspaceRoot specifies the workspace absolute path to the webserver root. used to resolve paths like /app.js to files on disk. Shorthand for a pathMapping for "/".

Comment: deechris I put my webRoot to this value:     "C:\\Users\\franc\\Desktop\\Angular js\\Progetti\\Modulo 5 facrtory service\\Codice Mio\\Begin\\src". is it correct?

Comment: no, it by default refers to the workspace folder where you the project files are located. let it be ${workspaceRoot}/src and try chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=8080.